# p and q are prime find valid solution for the following equation.

Tags: number-theory

If $p$ and $q$ are prime, find all pairs for $(p,q)$ for

$$p^q+1=q^p$$

I tried to solve this by assuming if $p$ wasn't equal to $2$,then $q$ has to be $2$, and by contradiction I concluded that $p=2$ and $q=3$.

Comment: Hint: use Mihailescu's theorem.

Comment: So i'm right?  Because my answer came to be p=2 and q=3

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thanks! But during a subjective examination would i have to write the proof or just state that through Mihailescu's theorem p=2 q=3?

Comment: Mihailescu's theorem is an overkill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without using Mihailescu's theorem, you can first reduce modulo $p$ to obtain $q \equiv 1 \pmod p$ and then reduce modulo $q$ to find $p \equiv -1 \pmod q$.

Thus $q$ divides $p + 1$ and $p$ divides $q - 1$.

In particular, $p \leq q - 1 \lt q \leq p + 1$. Due to the strict inequality, this is only possible if $p = q - 1$ and $q = p + 1$, which means $p = 2$ and $q = 3$.

And indeed, we check that $2^3 + 1 = 9 = 3^2$ so this is a solution.

Comment: Of course you are right :) I will add this for completeness.

Comment: Also note that this only works when $p$ and $q$ are prime because we made use of Fermat"s Little Theorem to say that $p^q \equiv p \pmod q$ and vice-versa.